# convert date format in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

Using this below code ,i converted the date format from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy.

```
date = report.manual_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

In other location i want to show the same date as like this format `27 may2013` in the template.

template is

```
{{ date }} at {{ time }}

{{ form.manual_date }}
```

How to convert the format to 27 May2013.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass the actual date to template then you can use [`date`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) formatting to show the date as you want.

For your case `{{ form.manual_date|date:"d NY" }}`

Comment: I tried this,the earlier format was disappeared,but no format change happens

Comment: @user2086641, what do you get?

Comment: {{ form.manual_date|date:"d NY" }} rendering as blank space,required format not got.

Comment: with out date filter,it is rendering the form field with existing format,if filter added then nothing comes to display

Comment: @user2086641, Otherwise pass another string for date format to template. You can create the string using `report.manual_date.strftime("%d %b%Y")`. Similar to what you have done.

Comment: By this way i can get the expected format,but their is one same gap between May and 2013 but for me their wont be any space between them is any way to do that.

Comment: @user2086641, I don't think there will be any space between them as its not specified in the format.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30675/discussion-between-user2086641-and-rohan)